# Strange behavior by the BDE Administrator

Tags: bde

Logged into my Windows XP SP2 computer using my normal user account (which has Local Admin privileges), when I start the BDE Administrator -- either from the Control Panel or from the BDEADMIN.EXE directly -- I never get the GUI.  It shows up on my task bar, and shows up in the Task Manager, but the GUI never appears.  I can close the program by right-clicking on the task bar and choosing close.  (note that "never" means not within 5 minutes of launching the program)

If I log into the same exact computer using a different user account (which also has Local Admin privileges), when I start the BDE Administrator, it loads the GUI within a couple seconds.

I used to be able to use the BDE Administrator while logged in under my normal user account, so it's not like this has always been a problem.

While this issue may not be directly programming related, it does make developing and testing a pain when I have to log off and back on a couple of times just to make changes to my BDE configuration.

I am totally stumped.  Any idea what might be causing this odd behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is that you may have had two screens running on this box and dragged the window off screen.

Just search for the registry keys that control where the window opens up and delete them.  Alternatively, you should be able to right click on the program in the task bar and select Move.  Then use your arrow keys to bring it back.

Regardless, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Genius!  That was it.  Must have dragged it off on one of the rare occasions when I had a second monitor.  I would have never thought of that.  Sorry for the lame question, but thank you for the great answer!